# Magento migration error 500

Tags: php, mysql, magento, migration, magento-1.8

I have a problem with my website under magento.
After migrating the site to another server, I get a 500 error.

**What I have done:**

- I copied files from one server to another by changing the app values>
  etc> local.xml with the new settings.
- I exported, imported the database on my new server by changing all
  references to my old domain name with the new.
- I have completed the script and magento-check everything is ok.

**Start of solution:**

When I run magento-cleanup script and I load the site, it works !!!
However, when I clicks on a link I have a 500 error again.
I raise the magento-cleanup script and then the page loads !!!

Same for the admin interface.

After uploaded the site on an OVH server, the site works correctly. It would seem that something is wrong with my .htaccess at Gandi server but not at OVH.

If anyone has a solution to deploy an existing installation of Magento on Gandi, I'm interested.
Maybe I will start a new installation of Magento and reinject later my info? But it seems to me anyway more complicated !!

Thanks for your help.

This is my htaccess:

```
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## default index file

DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

php_value memory_limit 256M
php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

php_flag session.auto_start off

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

#RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

#RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteRule ^villas(/.+)*  /fr/villas$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^maisons(/.+)*  /fr/maisons$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^appartements(/.+)*  /fr/appartements$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^prestige(/.+)*  /fr/prestige$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^carte-des-locations-de-vacances(/.+)*  /fr/carte-des-locations-de-vacances/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^conciergerie(/.+)*  /fr/conciergerie$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^offres-speciales(/.+)*  /fr/offres-speciales$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^polynesie-francaise(/.+)*  /fr/polynesie-francaise$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^evenements(/.+)*  /fr/evenements$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^assurance(/.+)*  /fr/assurance$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^paiement(/.+)*  /fr/paiement$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^proprietaires(/.+)*  /fr/proprietaires$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^qui-sommes-nous(/.+)*  /fr/qui-sommes-nous$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^engagements(/.+)*  /fr/engagements$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^agents-de-voyages(/.+)*  /fr/agents-de-voyages$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^mentions-legales-et-credits(/.+)*  /fr/mentions-legales-et-credits$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^contacts(/.+)*  /fr/contacts$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^conditions-generales-de-location(/.+)*  /fr/conditions-generales-de-location$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^houses(/.+)*  /en/houses$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^condos(/.+)*  /en/condos$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^special-offers(/.+)*  /en/special-offers$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^french-polynesia(/.+)*  /en/french-polynesia$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^concierge-service(/.+)*  /en/concierge-service$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^insurance(/.+)*  /en/insurance$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^payment(/.+)*  /en/payment$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^about-us(/.+)*  /en/about-us$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^commitments(/.+)*  /en/commitments$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^travel-agents(/.+)*  /en/travel-agents$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^legal-mentions-credits(/.+)*  /en/legal-mentions-credits$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^general-rental-terms(/.+)*  /en/general-rental-terms$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^payment(/.+)*  /en/payment$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^en/$  /en/home [L,R=301]

## page CMS en=>fr
RewriteRule ^fr/special-offers(/.+)*  /fr/offres-speciales [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^fr/french-polynesia(/.+)*  /fr/polynesie-francaise [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^fr/concierge-service(/.+)*  /fr/conciergerie [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^fr/events(/.+)*  /fr/evenements [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^fr/insurance(/.+)*  /fr/assurance [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^fr/payment(/.+)*  /fr/paiement [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^fr/about-us(/.+)*  /fr/qui-sommes-nous [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^fr/commitments(/.+)*  /fr/engagements [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^fr/travel-agents(/.+)*  /fr/agents-de-voyages [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^fr/rental-map(/.+)*  /fr/carte-des-locations-de-vacances [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^fr/legal-mentions-credits(/.+)*  /fr/mentions-legales-et-credits [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^fr/general-rental-terms(/.+)*  /fr/conditions-generales-de-location [L,R=301]

## page CMS fr=>en
RewriteRule ^en/offres-speciales(/.+)*  /en/special-offers [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^en/polynesie-francaise(/.+)*  /en/french-polynesia [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^en/conciergerie(/.+)*  /en/concierge-service [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^en/evenements(/.+)*  /en/events [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^en/assurance(/.+)*  /en/insurance [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^en/paiement(/.+)*  /en/payment [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^en/qui-sommes-nous(/.+)*  /en/about-us [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^en/engagements(/.+)*  /en/commitments [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^en/agents-de-voyages(/.+)*  /en/travel-agents [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^en/carte-des-locations-de-vacances(/.+)*  /en/rental-map [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^en/mentions-legales-et-credits(/.+)*  /en/legal-mentions-credits [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^en/conditions-generales-de-location(/.+)*  /en/general-rental-terms [L,R=301]


############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

AddDefaultCharset Off
#AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

Order allow,deny
Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

<Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

#FileETag none
```

`

Comment: check php error logs to see what the error is and share it with us

Comment: Hello,
I have not error in the php error log.

**Apache log:**
`[: error] [pid 24865: 3273234913024 tid] (104) Connection reset by peer: [113.197.68.117:60162 client] FastCGI: failed to read from backend server`

**Boot>console.log:**
`Starting apache2
.Services started
egrep: write error: Broken pipe
apache2 status exited with code 1, doublechecking ...`

It seems that the problem probably comes from the Apache URL rewriting (.htaccess or magento config) but I can not solve my problem

Comment: I also have an error in **fpm log** when I load the site:

`[09-Dec-2015 10:18:46] WARNING: [pool www] child 24959 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 0.929094 seconds from start`

Comment: what version of php are you using? do a `php -v` in the console or create a file with a call to `phpinfo()` in it and execute it

Comment: The site is hosted on Gandi Server and PHP Version 5.4.42-0+deb7u1.1

Answer (score 0):

500 could be caused by so many things so some log would be very helpful.
My first guess would be checking your file permission. Then if you can replicate this error on your local environment, edit your index.php and enable this line: 
`ini_set(‘display_errors’, 1);`
You shouldn't post your domain name here anyway.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help !!

In my local environment, the site loads but when I click a link I get an error 404.

Example link: `www/en/houses.html`

When I add index.php in URL like this:
`www/index.php/en/houses.html`, the page loads correctly.

Comment: hmm it seems like a different issue. I'm 99% sure that if you need to add index.php, you have problem with your .htaccess file.
Can you make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled and you have allow override directive set up correctly.  if you use nginx then you have to set them all up in your conf

Comment: I use Apache, mod_rewrite is active and AllowOverride set to All.
The htaccess works on the old serveur but not on new and not in local (except with adding index.php.